# convert this into linq or lambda c#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Can someone please help me convert this SQL to linq or lambda c#

```
select  
    count(s.ClassId) [StudentInClass], c.Name [Class], t.Name [teacher]
from 
    [dbo].[Students] s
inner join 
    class c on s.ClassId = c.Id
inner join Teacher t 
    on t.Id = c.TeacherId
group by 
    s.ClassId, c.Name, t.Name
```

so far this is what I have, and i am messing it up.  I want to achieve the same results as in my sql query

```
        SchoolEntities db = new SchoolEntities();

        var StudentsByCourseId = from s in db.Students
            join c in db.Classes on s.ClassId equals c.Id
            join t in db.Teachers on c.TeacherId equals t.Id
            group c by s.ClassId
            into g
            select g;
```

in SQL this is what my reults look like, it counts the students in a class by the teacher

```
 
          StudentCount  Class        Teacher
          1             Geography    Teacher1
          1             Biology      Teacher1
          2             Maths        Teacher2
```

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? Which are entities themselves?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include *attempted solutions*, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: LINQ to what? LINQ to SQL? LINQ to Entities? How is your context set? What have you tried already?

Comment: yesIi am using this to get the context  SchoolEntities db = new SchoolEntities();  The tables being used are Teacher, Class, Student

Comment: Now that you've posted an attempted solution, what problems are you having with that code?  In what way is it not working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an anonymous class to group by multiple properties.

```
 var StudentsByCourseId = from s in db.Students
            join c in db.Classes on s.ClassId equals c.Id
            join t in db.Teachers on c.TeacherId equals t.Id
            group s by new { s.ClassId, Class = c.Name, Teacher = t.Name } 
            into g
            select new
            {
              StudentInClass = g.Count(),
              g.Key.Class,
              g.Key.Teacher,
            };
```

Comment: I altered this to suit my needs and the result is posted in the original post.  As it would not let me post my own answer for 8 hours